# React Native Background Fetch not triggering

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to call a `supabase` function that checks for new messages with a `subscription`.
I am using `React-Native-Background-Fetch` I have implemented the call from the docs in the `index.ios.js` file. I am getting the `hello-world` call on the `setTimeout` but that is where the logs end.

What am I doing wrong?

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Hello, World!');
}, 900000);
const initBackgroundFetch = async () => {
  console.log('initBackgroundFetch');
  try {
    await BackgroundFetch.configure(
      {
        minimumFetchInterval: 15,
        stopOnTerminate: false,
        startOnBoot: true,
        enableHeadless: true,
        requiresBatteryNotLow: false,
        requiresCharging: false,
        requiresStorageNotLow: false,
        requiresDeviceIdle: false,
        forceAlarmManager: false,
      },
      async taskId => {
        console.log('[BackgroundFetch] taskId:', taskId);
        supabase.channel('CONVERSATION_MESSAGES').on('INSERT', payload => {
          console.log('INSERT', payload);
          notifee.displayNotification({
            title: 'New Message',
            body: payload.new.message,
          });
        });
        BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('[BackgroundFetch] configure error:', error);
      },
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('[BackgroundFetch] configuration error:', error);
  }
};

initBackgroundFetch(); // Call the function to register BackgroundFetch
```